# Explode with operator

Tags: php, operators, explode

I have a working code to restrict & validate subdomain.

```
 $exp = explode('.', 'blog.mydomain.my.');

 print_r($exp);
 if(count($exp) == 3 && $exp[1] == "mydomain" && $exp[2] == "my" || $exp[3] == "") {
    echo "<br>";
  echo 'subdomain valid';
 } else{
    echo "<br>";
  echo 'not valid';
 }
```

now it need to check if its only false and I'm not so sure about the `$exp[3] != ""` comparison. From example below the subdomain should be valid but it give me error.

```
 echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
 $exp2 = explode('.', 'blog.mydomain.my.');

 print_r($exp2);
 if(count($exp2) != 3 || $exp2[1] != "mydomain" || $exp2[2] != "my" || $exp[3] != "") {
    echo "<br>";
  echo 'not valid';
 }
```

Accepted numbers of subdomain is `hello.mydomain.my` or `hello.mydomain.my.` (with trailing dot). While `hello.world.mydomain.my` is not accepted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error exactly ? Is the code not working ?

Comment: I feel like either you should be checking if `count($exp2) != 4` or you should take off the last condition, as if the count is 3 the last condition should go out of bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want.

```
if(count($exp2) < 3 || count($exp2) > 4 || $exp2[1] != "mydomain" || $exp2[2] != "my" || (count($exp2) != 4 && $exp[3] != "")) {
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'not valid';
}
```

Comment: Why not regex? $valid = preg_match('/^hello\.domain\.my\.?$/', $domain) ? true : false;

Comment: @AlexP with a different subdomain pattern that would work as well. You should refine and post that as an answer...I would upvote

Comment: just to understand your code.. subdomain will be `not valid` if `ONE` of the statement match the criteria and to be `valid` `all statement` must not match the criteria?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a regex solution, possibly even `encapsulate` it in a function:

```
function isValidDomain($domain) 
{
  return preg_match('/^[\w]+\.(mydomain)\.(my)\.?$/', $domain) ? true : false;
}

var_dump(isValidDomain('www.google.com'));
var_dump(isValidDomain('test.invalid.domain'));
var_dump(isValidDomain('hello.mydomain.my'));
var_dump(isValidDomain('hello.mydomain.my.'));
```

Comment: I think the intent was for any subdomain to match so maybe `'/^[\w]+\.(mydomain)\.(my)\.?$/'`

Comment: Yes any subdomain to match with my domain.